# IPP filter functions

Tags: opencv, intel-ipp

I am new on IPP. My question is, I wrote a piece of code for filtering images in Intel IPP but my code is not working properly. I am using the same image as the input every time. Here is my code. What is wrong?

```
Mat img = imread("image.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Mat outImg = img.clone();

int step = img.cols; //pitch

IppiSize size;
size.width = img.cols; // size of IPP images is the same
size.height = img.rows; // as read image img

vector<Ipp8u> aBuffer(1);

ippiFilterSharpenBorder_8u_C1R((const Ipp8u*)&img.data[0], step, (Ipp8u*)&outImg.data[0], step, size, ippMskSize5x5, ippBorderConst, 0, aBuffer.data());

imshow("Out", outImg);
```

Comment: what is the result/error/problem?

Comment: Input image and output image is same. Nothing changed. I mean nothing happening.

Comment: width should be cols and height rows. What's the buffer used for? Maybe size 1 is a bit low there?

Comment: According to documentation, you need to get working buffer size by calling ippiFilterSharpenBorderGetBufferSize and allocate aBuffer according to that size. Then, check ippiFilterSharpenBorder_8u_C1R status after call. Verify if "step" is ok. Is it equal to cols*elemSize()?. And - Micka is right! - width=cols, height=rows.

Comment: I fixed cols and rows and i checked documentation, you are right we have to use ippiFilterSharpenBorderGetBufferSize function. But i didn't understand how i will entegrate  function in my code block? And what iss buffer for?